# find nearest longitude in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search with longitude and latitude, if I want to search some place (longitude 50.2122211145, latitude 30.02111454) then I want result who is near with these values in our database (around 20 km) How can I do like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(50.2122211145) ) + sin( radians(30.02111454) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 20 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

See this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance) and this [document](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)

Comment: @Ritu in query i have `lat` and `lng`, change them to your respective column names of your db. like `latitude` and `longitude`.

Comment: i think there is no data in your db. all places are far. i mean distance is more than 25. replace 25 with `2500`.

Comment: the above is wrking query. i have used in my project. its working fine

Comment: populate your db for more values.

Comment: plz see above screenshot

Comment: remove `having distance < 20` clause. and try once.